# pass arguments into python script node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am trying to run a python script from node.js, see below:

```
    app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

       let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
       //you can use error handling to see if there are any errors
       let options = {
         id: 'xxxxxxx'
       }
  
       PythonShell.run('../session1.py', options, function (err, results) {
         console.log(results)
       })
    })
```

and in python, I have this:

```
async def main(options) -> None:
"""Create the aiohttp session and run the example."""
logging.basicConfig(level=LOGLEVEL)
async with ClientSession() as websession:
    try:
        print(sys.argv)
    except MyQError as err:
        _LOGGER.error("There was an error: %s", err)
```

I don't know how to use the options I pass to the python script. When I log `results` in node.js, it doesn't use the `options`, it just prints out other stuff I have in the function

Comment: Arguments are specified with `args: [...]` in the `options` objet.

Comment: This is shown in the example titled **Running a Python script with arguments and options** in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)

Comment: @Barmar thanks for that. Just as you messaged that, I saw that problem in my code lol. Thanks for sharing the resource though, will take a peak